# Need help showing content from redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to retrieve information from my backend and display it. I can fetch the data to my redux store fine but when I try to display it on the page I get a cannot read property 'title' of undefined error. Doesn't always occur but whenever I refresh it does. Any ideas? Here is the file in question. Happy to share other information but I am pretty confident both my backend and redux are working properly because I can retrieve and display data elsewhere.

```
import '../../styles/article.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getThread } from '../../store/actions/forum_actions';
import { clearThread } from '../../store/actions';
const Thread = (props) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const threads = useSelector((state) => state.threads);
  const thread = threads?.current;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getThread(props.match.params.id));
    setLoading(false);
  }, [dispatch, props.match.params.id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      dispatch(clearThread());
    };
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <>
          <p>Loading</p>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <p>{thread.title}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Thread;
```

Here is the reducer:

```
import { ADD_THREAD, GET_THREADS, GET_THREAD, CLEAR_THREAD } from '../types';

export default function threadReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_THREAD:
      return { ...state, lastThreadAdded: action.payload, success: true };
    case GET_THREADS:
      return { ...state, threads: action.payload };
    case GET_THREAD:
      return { ...state, current: action.payload };
    case CLEAR_THREAD:
      return { ...state, current: null };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here is the action

```
import * as threads from './index';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getAuthHeaders } from '../../components/utils/tools';

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

export const getThread = (id) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const request = await axios.get(`/forum/thread/${id}`);
    dispatch(threads.getThread(request.data));

    try {
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(threads.errorGlobal('Error retrieving thread'));
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: can you show us reducer? what is the initial state? what do you store in threads.current?

Comment: @Kasia I updated the post with more information. Threads.current stores one thread retrieved by ID. it contains title, author, content, comments, date, etc and it shows up in the store correctly I just cant get the info to display

Comment: UPDATE: I conditionally rendered all content coming from the store by putting them in an if(threads.current) {....} and that fixed the issue. Anyone know why?

Comment: But your loading state probably will still be buggy, you need to move your loading state to redux.
Check ans below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's happening is because the action you are dispatching is Async (`dispatch(getThread(props.match.params.id));`) and hence code execution will not wait for the API result it will execute the next statement which is `setLoading(false)`.
You are making your loading stop before API response and hence you are getting undefined error.

Solution:

Reduder:

```
import { ADD_THREAD, GET_THREADS, GET_THREAD, CLEAR_THREAD, LOADING_THREAD } from '../types';

export default function threadReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOADING_THREAD:
      return { ...state, loadingThreads: action.payload }; //modified
    case ADD_THREAD:
      return { ...state, lastThreadAdded: action.payload, success: true };
    case GET_THREADS:
      return { ...state, threads: action.payload };
    case GET_THREAD:
      return { ...state, current: action.payload };
    case CLEAR_THREAD:
      return { ...state, current: null };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Action:

```
import * as threads from './index';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getAuthHeaders } from '../../components/utils/tools';

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

export const getThread = (id) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
try {
    dispatch(threads.loadingThread(true));
    const request = await axios.get(`/forum/thread/${id}`);
    dispatch(threads.getThread(request.data));
    dispatch(threads.loadingThread(false));

    
    } catch (error) {
    dispatch(threads.loadingThread(false));
      dispatch(threads.errorGlobal('Error retrieving thread'));
    }
  };
};
```

Component:

```
import '../../styles/article.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getThread } from '../../store/actions/forum_actions';
import { clearThread } from '../../store/actions';
const Thread = (props) => {
  const threads = useSelector((state) => state.threads);
  const loading = useSelector((state) => state.loadingThreads); //modified
  const thread = threads?.current;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getThread(props.match.params.id));
    setLoading(false);
  }, [dispatch, props.match.params.id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      dispatch(clearThread());
    };
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <>
          <p>Loading</p>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <p>{thread.title}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Thread;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have defined initialState for the reducer

instead

`state = {}`

```
const initialState = {
current:{},
threads: [],
success: false 
}

function threadReducer(state = initialState, action)
```

this will help you managing the in-between state.

Also loading state in the component is not always aligned. Consider using

`isLoading = useSelector(loadingSelector)`

instead `useState`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify Redux async flows implementing the repository pattern without a middleware to handle an API call and dispatch a state. Api calls can be also encapsulated into hooks. For example, take a look to this piece of code, it's not related to your project, but you can use it as a starting point:

```
export const useCustomerRepository = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<CustomerAction>>();

  const customerState = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.customerState);
  const customerApi = useCustomerApi();

  const list = async () => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: 'CUSTOMER:LISTING', flag: true });
      const customers = await handleAxiosApi<Customer[]>(customerApi.list());
      dispatch({ type: 'CUSTOMER:LIST', customers });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: 'CUSTOMER:LIST_FAILED', message: getResponseErrorMessage(error) });
    } finally {
      dispatch({ type: 'CUSTOMER:LISTING', flag: false });
    }
  };

  return {...customerState};
};
```

You can take a look to the [full working example here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyajJetOyg) to simplify your code.